# Как сделать переменную доступной для всех контроллеров (на примере Корзины покупателя)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я учусь Ruby по книге "Agile Development with Ruby", на примере создания электронного магазина.

У каждой сессии создается своя корзина (`cart`), и в неё добавляются товарные позиции (`listing_line`). Мне хотелось бы вывести в шапку количество всех товаров в корзине для текущего пользователя.

Я создал парциальный шаблон `_cart`, который считает количество всех товаров:

```
 <% sum = 0 %>
    <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
          <% sum = sum + item.quantity %>
      <% end %>
     <%= sum %>
```

Но когда я добавляю его в шапку, то (естественно) каждая страница выдает ошибку о том, что не знает переменную `@cart`. Как лучше всего поступить с этим? Прописать в каждый контроллер (`store`, `category`, `product`) значение переменной, или же его можно куда-то записать (куда?), чтобы оно было доступно всем контроллерам? Будет ли это безопасно в будущем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все контроллеры от чего-то наследуются. Чаще всего от `ApplicationController`.

```
#ApplicationController
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Перед вызовом каждого экшена выполнять метод указанный в качестве аргумента
  before_action :set_cart 

  private

  def set_cart
    # такая-то логика, создающая переменную экземпляра @cart
    @cart = ...
  end
end
```

Теперь, во всех экшенах будет доступна переменная `@cart`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Открытый вопрос о том будет ли это безопасно.

Comment: Безопасно что? Создавать переменную экземпляра класса?

Comment: @Mistthrt то, принцип работы чего не понимаете, небезопасно. Вопрос только в том, парит ли вас это конкретное место. Если парит -- изучите, как работает, тогда возникнут критерии поточнее.